# Gradle task take over configuration of war

Tags: gradle, war

For my web project I need to build two WAR files.
One with the static content, one without.

```
war {
    archiveName = "feeder##${version}.full.war"
    exclude 'test.html', 'test.js', 'todos.js'
}
task SmallWar(type: War, dependsOn:[war]) {
    // exclude 'css', 'img', 'js', 'template', 'index.html'
    archiveName = "feeder##${version}.war"
}
```

It's clear, I'm able to configure both the same way, but how can I take over the configuration and enhance it?
The current configuration only calls `war` before running `SmallWar`.
I don't want to call it. Instead the `SmallWar` task should already exclude the same files as the war plus additional files.

Comment: Does it not help if you declare a variable to hold'test.html', 'test.js', 'todos.js' exclude patterns and use it in war task and SmallWar task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dependsOn` only affects execution, not configuration. An easy way to configure commonalities between the two `War` tasks is:

```
tasks.withType(War) {
    exclude 'test.html', 'test.js', 'todos.js'
}
```

`smallWar` can then add further excludes:

```
task smallWar(type: War) {
    exclude 'css', 'img', 'js'
}
```